# cannot resolve method 'toByteArray()'

Tags: android-fragments

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.ak.locationsviewer", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.**toByteArray()**);
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong class.

You should use `android.content.pm.Signature` instead of `java.security.Signature`.